# python, lógica em lista - remover item

Tags: python, lista

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo baseado em *zombie dice*, em Python.

Estou com problema especificamente no uso da lista `copo[]` , em que preciso remover os dados jogados e posteriormente recolocá-los no jogo usando a função `adicionar_dados()` que eu defini, porém ao rodar o programa acabo encontrando o erro:

> *IndexError: list index out of range*.

Onde estou errando?

Segue abaixo o código:

```
import random


comeca_partida = False

#define dados
dado_verde = "C,P,C,T,P,C"  # 6 dados verdes
dado_amarelo = "T,P,C,T,P,C"  # 4 dados amarelos
dado_vermelho = "T,P,T,C,P,T"  # 3 dados vermelhos

copo = []


def adicionar_dados():    #adicionar os dados
    for i in range(0, 6):
        copo.append(dado_verde)
    for i in range(0, 4):
        copo.append(dado_amarelo)
    for i in range(0, 3):
        copo.append(dado_vermelho)


turno = 0

numero_jogadores = int(input("Digite o número de jogadores na partida: \n"))
lista_jogadores = []
for ind in range(0, numero_jogadores):
    nome = input("Qual o nome do jogador? \n")

if numero_jogadores >= 2:
    comeca_partida = True # iniciar a partida
    cerebros = 0
    tiros = 0
    adicionar_dados()
    i = 1
    while (i < numero_jogadores +1):
        player = dict({'jogador': i, 'cerebros': 0, 'tiros': 0})
        lista_jogadores.append(player)
        i = i + 1

        print("Partida iniciada! ")

        while comeca_partida == True:
            for player[i] in lista_jogadores:
                try:
                    print("\n olá, {}, digite o que deseja fazer:".format(nome))
                    jogar = int(input("[1] - Jogar os dados, [2] Finalziar turno ou [3] Trocar de jogador: \n"))
                except:
                    print("valor inválido!")

                if jogar == 1:
                    for i in range(0, 3):
                        num_sorteado = int(random.randrange(0, 12))
                        print("Dado sorteado {}: {} ".format((i + 1), num_sorteado))

                        dado_sorteado = copo[num_sorteado]  # 'lança' o dado e verifica qual a face sorteada
                        face_dado = int(random.randrange(0, 5))  # obtem a face do dado

                        if dado_sorteado[face_dado] == "C":  # tirou "cerebro no dado
                            print("Você comeu um cérebro!!")
                            cerebros = cerebros + 1
                            copo.remove(dado_sorteado)

                        elif dado_sorteado[face_dado] == "T":  # tirou tiro no dado
                            print("Você levou um tiro!!")
                            tiros = tiros + 1
                            copo.remove(dado_sorteado)

                        else:
                            print("A vítima escapou!!")


                elif jogar == 2:
                    pontos = cerebros
                    print("Turno finalizado! Fez", pontos, "pontos!")
                    print(lista_jogadores)
                    turno += 1
                    tiros = 0

                elif jogar == 3:
                    print("Próximo jogador!")
                    adicionar_dados()
                    #trocar jogador ???

    else:
        print("O jogo precisa de 2 ou mais jogadores!")
```

Comment: Olá, Ricardo, o erro está acontecendo porque você remove os itens da lista `copo` a cada rodada, porém a variável `num_sorteado` continua sorteando um número de 0 a 11, então, quando seu dado só possui, por exemplo, 6 itens restantes, e é sorteado o número 9, retornará este erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o Felipe alertou no comentário da pergunta, esse erro está acontecendo após você iniciar a partida quando o jogador seleciona a opção `'1'`. Nesse momento você sorteia um número aleatório entre `[0,11]` com a intenção de selecionar um dos dados do jogo e em seguida retirar ele da 'caixa de dados' para o jogador não ter a chance de retirar esse dado novamente (pelo menos até o próximo turno).
Porém quando você usa o método `.remove()`, um elemento é retirado da lista, e eventualmente isso causa problemas, porque você continua sorteando um número aleatório entre `[0, 11]`, mas a sua lista já não tem mais os 12 elementos iniciais. 
Uma forma de você consertar isso é ao invés de sortear um número aleatório entre `[0,11]` sortear no intervalo `[0, len(copo)]`:

```
...
if jogar == 1:
  for i in range(0, 3):
    num_sorteado = int(random.randrange(0, len(copo)))
    print("Dado sorteado {}: {} ".format((i + 1), num_sorteado))
...
```

Boa sorte com o programa!

Comment: muito obrigado, João!